# Minio / Keycloak integration: connection refused

Tags: docker, keycloak, minio

I am trying to connect MinIO with KeyCloak and I follow the instructions provided in this documentation: 
https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/sts/keycloak.md

What I have done so far is deploy a Docker container for the MinIO server, another one for the MinioClient and a third one used for the KeyCloak server.

---

As you can see in the following snippet the configuration of the Minio Client container is done correctly, since I can list the buckets available in the Minio Server:

```sh
mc ls myminio
[2020-05-14 11:54:59 UTC]      0B bucket1/
[2020-05-06 12:23:01 UTC]      0B bucket2/
```

---

I have an issue arising when I try to configure MinIO as depicted in **step 3 (Configure MinIO)** of the documentation. In more detail, the command that I run is this one:

```
mc admin config set myminio identity_openid config_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration" client_id="account"
```

And the error I get is this one:

```
mc: <ERROR> Cannot set 'identity_openid config_url=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration client_id=account' to server. Get http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused.
```

When I curl this address `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration` from the MinIO Client container though,  I retrieve the JSON file.

Comment: Can you share the dockerfile here and also the docker-compose file if you are using it. So that we can dig into the problem.

Comment: I am not using docker-compose nor have I created a Dockerfile. I just run the containers based on the images on docker hub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, all I had to do is change the `localhost` in the `config_url`, from `localhost` to the IP of the KeyCloak container (`172.17.0.3`).

This is just a temporary solution that works for now, but I will continue searching for something more concrete than just hardcoding the IP.

When I figure out the solution, this answer will be updated.

### Update

I had to create a `docker-compose.yml` file as the one below in order to overcome the issues without having to manually place the IP of the KeyCloak container.

```
version: '2'
services:

  miniod:
    image: minio/minio
    restart: always
    container_name: miniod 
    ports:
    - 9000:9000
    volumes:
    - "C:/data:/data"
    environment:
    - "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=access_key" 
    - "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=secret_key"
    command: ["server", "/data"]
    networks:
    - minionw

  mcd:
    image: minio/mc 
    container_name: mcd
    networks:
    - minionw

  kcd: 
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
    container_name: kcd
    restart: always
    ports: 
    - 8080:8080
    environment: 
    - "KEYCLOAK_USER=admin"
    - "KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=pass"
    networks: 
    - minionw

networks:
  minionw: 
    driver: "bridge"
```

Comment: Yes! This seems to work for me too with the 192.168 subnet IP of the keycloak container

Answer (score 0):

`Connection refused` occurs when a port is not accessible on the hostname or IP we specified. 
Please try exposing the port using `--expose` flag along with the port number which you wish to expose when using the docker CLI. Then being exposed, you can access on it on `localhost`